# Get number of lines StaticLayout will split text into

Tags: android, layout, android-canvas

I'm drawing some text onto a canvas, and am using a StaticLayout to wrap the text across the screen. I want to align the text so that the bottom of the text is on the bottom of the screen.

To do this I need to know how many lines the StaticLayout has wrapped the text into, so i can multiply that by the font size, and offset it that much from the height of my component.

This is my StaticLayout:

```
main = new TextPaint();
main.setTextSize(textSize);
main.setColor(Color.WHITE);
bottomText = new StaticLayout("Long text that requires wrapping.", main, getWidth(), Layout.Alignment.ALIGN_CENTER, 1f, 1.0f, false);
```

And I'm moving it down by translating my canvas:

```
canvas.translate(0, getHeight() / 2);
bottomText.draw(canvas);
canvas.restore();
```

So; how do I align it to the bottom, or get the number of lines it has been split into?

Answer (score 6):

How about `StaticLayout.getLineCount()`?